# How to incorporate directory with spaces into windows batch script, double quotes within single quotes

Tags: batch-file

Simple question (Windows batch) but hard to find a specific answer.

How do I incorporate this:

```
DIR "T:\Some Directory\Another Dir" /S /B /A-D
```

into this:

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR "T:\Some Directory\Another Dir" /S /B /A-D ^| FINDSTR /EVIL ".jpg .JPG .mp4 .MP4"') DO
```

I'm getting problems with the quotes of the directory - the command is looking for "T:\Some" because the directory is split at SPACE.

Have tried escaping ^, double quotes, triple quotes etc. with no effect...

The problem is double quotes within single quotes I guess...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the `For` loop to ignore its default whitespace delimiters.

You can use either:

```bat
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('
    DIR/B/S/A-D-S-L "T:\Some Directory\Another Dir"^|FindStr/EVIL ".jpg .mp4"
') DO …
```

or:

```bat
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('DIR/B/S/A-D-S-L "T:\Some Directory\Another Dir"'
) DO IF /I NOT "%%~xA"==".jpg" IF /I NOT "%%~nxA"==".mp4" (…
```